# Updating dictionary value after using dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, django

I can update a nested dictionary after initialising it using a for loop but not after using dictionary comprehension . Why is that ?

This works:

```
def calendar_init(year, month, habits):
    date_list = dates_in_month(year, month)
    calendar_init = dict()
    for mydate in date_list:
        calendar_init[mydate] = {'mood': None}
        for habit in habits:
            calendar_init[mydate][habit] = None
    return calendar_init

def create_calendar(year, month, habits, entries, moods):
    new_calendar = calendar_init(year, month, habits)

    for entry in entries:
        new_calendar[entry.day][entry.habit] = entry
    for mood in moods:
        new_calendar[mood.day]['mood'] = mood

    return new_calendar
```

but this doesn't:

```
def calendar_init(year, month, habits):
    date_list = dates_in_month(year, month)
    merged_dict = {**dict.fromkeys(habits, None), **{'mood': None}}
    calendar_init = {mydate: merged_dict for mydate in date_list}
    return calendar_init

def create_calendar(year, month, habits, entries, moods):
    new_calendar = calendar_init(year, month, habits)

    for entry in entries:
        new_calendar[entry.day][entry.habit] = entry
    for mood in moods:
        new_calendar[mood.day]['mood'] = mood

    return new_calendar
```

Comment: You definitely *can*, since there is no different. It does not construct a "different" dictionary. The problem is however that here you refer to the *same* dictionary for all keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely *can* update, since there is no difference in the object constructed. The problem here is that all keys refer to the *same* dictionary object as values, not different objects with (possibly) the same data.

You thus can make copies of the dictionary with:

```
def calendar_init(year, month, habits):
    date_list = dates_in_month(year, month)
    merged_dict = {**dict.fromkeys(habits, None), **{'mood': None}}
    calendar_init = {mydate: dict(merged_dict) for mydate in date_list}
    return calendar_init
```

Comment: good lord, I spent my entire weekend on this and it took you 37 seconds... THANK YOU!