# Update dictionary values with dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to update a dictionary where the keys are the last name of a person and the values are the first names (so if 2 people have the same last name, their first names would be the values)

I first did this with normal loops:

```
name_dict = {}

with open("names.txt","r") as file:
    for line in file:
        line = line.strip()
        line = line.split(" ")
        
        if line[-1] not in name_dict:
            name_dict[line[-1]] = [line[0]]
        else:
            name_dict[line[-1]].append(line[0])
```

and that worked just fine, but now I'd like to use comprehension and I was trying something like this:

```
name_dict_2 = {}
with open("names.txt","r") as file:
    for line in file:
        line = line.strip()
        line = line.split(" ")

        name_dict_2 = {p[-1]:[p[0]] if p[-1] not in name_dict_2 else name_dict_2[p[-1]].append([p[0]]) for p in line }
```

and I keep getting  `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'`. Any help is very welcome!

I was taking a look at this SO: [Updating dictionary value after using dictionary comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60477997/updating-dictionary-value-after-using-dictionary-comprehension), but I don't think this would be the appropriate method for this problem

Answer (score 0):

You can't group element in a dict comprehension, the best you could do is to use `dict.setdefault` or a `defaultdict`

With come nice unpacking you have

```
from collections import defaultdict

name_dict = defaultdict(list)
with open("names.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        first, *_, last = line.strip().split(" ")
        name_dict[first].append(last)
```

Comment: Thank you for the input! So there is no way of doing this with "vanilla" python, correct?